# Accessing random rows from database without repetition

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have designed a quiz scenario using MySQL database as my backend.

I have a total of `20` questions and I would want to display them in random order from the database.
I have tried :

```
SELECT * from mst_que ORDER BY RAND();
```

What the above query does is repeat few rows.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database, it's a web application for working with MySQL databases.

Comment: The query should not repeat anything, unless your table has duplicate rows to begin with. You could use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Sir, sorry my bad MySQL in PHP

Comment: Correct, that query will return only the 20 rows in random order.

Comment: Please help Sir

Comment: PHP is irrelevant, the results of a query have nothing to do with the language you use to write the client application.

Comment: Does the complete query go like SELECT DISTINCT FROM mst_que                                               and yes my database does not have any duplicate rows

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mst_que ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: DISTINCT is only if you have duplicates in the database. Then the question is why you have duplicate questions?

Comment: No sir. i have rechecked. there are no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If the table contains duplicate records, use `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter them out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM mst_que
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score -2):

The `order by` clausule needs column names or relative positions <del>, not values or values. So</del>. Try to add the RAND to the select and order by it.
Try this:

```
SELECT *, RAND() as ordering
FROM mst_que
ORDER by ordering;
```

Comment: This is not true, `ORDER BY RAND()` is a very common idiom and works fine.

Comment: `ORDER BY` can be followed by any expression, it doesn't have to be a column name.

Comment: Sir it is still repeating.

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: que_id que_desc ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4 true_ans                                                   que_id is int                                                                                                    rest is all varchar @Pep Lainez

Comment: is there a possibility we can use WHERE NOT IN clause

Comment: How many rows are you reading at once? All the rows in the table or only a few of them?

Comment: @Pep Lainez Sir, all of them at once                                                                                             Displaying Questions at top and the answers as choices

Comment: Did you tried if the query is working properly in MySQL workbench? Maybe the problem is in the code that prints out the data.

Comment: Sir @Pep Lainez i just tried it out in sql workbench and it is returning distinct rows                                                                                                                                                                                                .But that doesnt seem to be the case otherwise :(

Comment: This query can't return duplicates if they are not in the table  as you saw when testing in the workbench.. Then the problem is in the code which is printing out the data.

Comment: @PepLainez Sir so what can I do ? Please Help

Comment: Just review the code that is printing your data. The problem should be there.

Comment: @PepLainez Sir i did recheck , whenever i give it as a query in sql database/workbench , it gives distinct rows (no repitition). but elsewhere its repeating

Comment: $rs=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `mst_que` ORDER BY RAND()") or die(mysql_error());


 
  if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
  {
    mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
    $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
 
    mysql_query("insert into usr_ans(que_id,ques_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]', '$row[5]','$row[6]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
    if($ans==$row[6])
    {
       $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
    }
    $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;

Comment: You are not displaying ALL questions in the SAME page. You are loading the data at every post and you are not controlling wich questions were displayed previously, so you can have repeated questions. 
That said, you need to add a kind of control of displayed questions, maybe storing the id's in the session, and then retrieving the questions from the database filtering the ones you have in session.

Comment: @PepLainez Sir, a line of code of how exactly thatcould be done, Please , it would help me a lot. please sir

Comment: something like this                                                         session_start();

$jsqla=mysql_query("select que_id from mst_que");
$jfeta=mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

 session_start();
    $id = array($jfeta['id']);;
    $_SESSION['id'][] = $id;
$rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mst_que` WHERE que_id NOT IN ('id') ORDER BY RAND() ")